# Recursive up-counter with one variable?

Tags: c, recursion, counter

I want to make an up-counting recursive function, to count from 1 to a random positive number but that random number is the only paramater I can give this function.
Is there even a way to do it with this limitations, it seems to me I at least need one more function given variable. A local variable just resets with a new recursion..

```
void numChainRecursive(int lastNum)
{
    if(lastNum > 0)
    {
        printf("%d", lastNum);
        numChainRecursive(lastNum - 1);
    }
}
```

example, if lastNum = 22, compiled I get "222120[...]1" but i want it to count up from 1 to 22

I could only solve this with another function given variable, but my goal was to use only one given parameter.

```
void numChainRecursive(int first, int last)
{
    if(first <= last)
    {
        printf("%d", first);
        numChainRecursive(first + 1, last);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the printout after the recursive call.

```
void numChainRecursive(int lastNum)
{
    if(lastNum > 0)
    {
        numChainRecursive(lastNum - 1);
        printf("%d", lastNum);
    }
}
```